# Subversion auto update problem (client is too old)

Tags: svn

svn: This client is too old to work with working copy 'D:\CemT\PublishFolder'
lease get a newer Subversion client?

Because i only can find subversion server systems not its command line client tools.
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to update you SVN Client

something like [Collabnet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) should work

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sliksvn.com/ (command line)
http://tortoisesvn.net/ (GUI)

Comment: I am answering the question implied in "I only can find subversion server systems not its command line client tools"

Answer (score 0):

They usually come in the same package. Depends what OS your on.

Comment: http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/ has the packages for windows, for instance, both server and client command line tools. The 2nd option is even client command line only.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the working copy?

For this message to occur, you needed to check out using a newer subversion client, and then try to update using an older client. This can happen for instance if you are using AnkSVN and TortoiseSVN and the one is newer than the other.

Update your SVN client!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

it seems this working copy has been checked out using a newer version of SVN client. try updating it or,  recheckout using the current client as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This means the metadata in your project refers to an old version of subversion. Upgrade it by following this guide: http://www.robsearles.com/2008/12/svn-client-is-too-old-to-work-with-working-copy-solution-using-rsync/